# Configure nginx to return different files to different authenticated users with the same URI

Tags: authentication, nginx, basic-authentication

I'm using nginx to serve static files in an embedded system, with no CGI back-end. I have basic-authentication up with multiple username/passwords. I'd like to have a specific URI deliver different content based on the name of the currently authenticated user.

For instance, let's say a browser requested URI /index.html. If the browser was authenticated as user "developer", then it could be served the file /index_developer.html. If instead the browser was authenticated as "administrator" it could be served the file /index_administrator.html.

I only want this redirection to occur on a small set of files; most will be served as-is. I'd also need to block direct access to the actual files so that nobody could do an end-run around the system.

Comment: Will you have `index_USER.html` for all `USER`s? Will it always be `index.html` or you need `/other.html` as well?

Comment: This system will have a very limited number of hard-coded users, so I'm open to either choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, there is variable [`$remote_user`](http://nginx.org/r/%24remote_user).

I've end up with following structure:

```
$ tree
.
├── _auth
│   ├── admin
│   │   ├── f
│   │   │   └── index.html
│   │   ├── hello.html
│   │   └── index.html
│   └── user
│       ├── f
│       │   └── index.html
│       └── index.html
├── f
│   └── x.html
├── hello.html
├── test.html
└── x
    └── index.html
```

and this nginx config:

```
auth_basic "Restricted area";
auth_basic_user_file path/to/passwd/file;

root /path/to/root;

location / {
    try_files /_auth/$remote_user$uri
              /_auth/$remote_user$uri/index.html
              $uri $uri/index.html =404;
}

location /_auth/ {
    internal;
}
```

So request to `/` will end up in `/_auth/USER/index.html`, request to `/test.html` will serve `/test.html`. And request to `/hello.html` will serve `/_auth/admin/hello.html` for user `admin` and `/hello.html` for any other user.

Direct access to `/_auth/..` is forbidden by `internal` directive.

Comment: I had to make some changes to get this to work; I changed `$remote_user$uri` to `$remote_user/$uri`, and made sure that every item in the `try_files` began with a `/` to prevent redirection loops. Works well!

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm accepting Alexy Ten's answer, as his insight was what got me there, I ended up using a slightly different scheme.

Instead of having the user-specific files residing in a completely separate tree, I chose to have them live right next to the generic files, but adding a standard prefix of `_user_<userName>_`. For instance, I might have the following two files in the webroot:

1. `/scripts/menus.js`
2. `/scripts/_user_developer_menus.js`

Then, if logged in as user "developer", a request for /scripts/menus.js would be served the second file, but with any other user the first file would be served.

Here is the core of my nginx configuration:

```
location ~ "^.*/_user_[^/]*$" {
    internal;
}

location ~ "^(.*)/([^/]*)$" {
    auth_basic_user_file /opt/product/cfg/nginx_conf/htpasswd;
    try_files   $1/_user_${remote_user}_$2$is_args$args
                $1/_user_${remote_user}_$2/index.html$is_args$args
                $1/$2$is_args$args
                $1/$2/index.html$is_args$args
                =404;
}
```

Since both locations are as specific (both regexes) they're searched in order. So, the first location blocks direct access to any of the `_user_<userName>_` files. The second location matches any URL, with the path up to the file name left in `$1`, and the file name left in `$1`. Then, the try_files looks for a user-specific file, a user-specific directory, a common file, and a common directory, in that order, until it gives up with a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Simple `root /path/to/root/$remote_user` is worked for me.

*Note:* if you use `$document_root` in `auth_basic_user_file` (like `auth_basic_user_file $document_root/.htpasswd;`), then your `.htpasswd` file should be in all subdirectories, not just root

```
$ tree -a
.
├── .htpasswd
├── user1
│   ├── hello1
│   └── .htpasswd -> ../.htpasswd
├── user2
│   ├── hello2
│   └── .htpasswd -> ../.htpasswd
└── user3
    ├── hello3
    └── .htpasswd -> ../.htpasswd
```