# Chrome over-caching .json files served from nginx

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, dojo

I'm using nginx and Dojo to build an embedded UI driven by a set of JSON files. Our primary target browser is Chrome, but it should work with all modern browsers.

Changing the JSON files can change the UI drastically, and I use this to give different presentations to different users. See my previous question for the details ([Configure nginx to return different files to different authenticated users with the same URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506626/configure-nginx-to-return-different-files-to-different-authenticated-users-with)), but basically my nginx configuration is such that the same URI with different users can yield different content.

This all works very well, except when someone switches to a different user. Some browsers will grab those JSON files from their own internal cache without even checking with the server, which leaves the UI display the previous user's presentation. Reloading the page fixes it, but boy! would I rather the right thing happened automatically.

The obvious solution is to use the various cache headers, but they don't appear to help. I'm using the following nginx directives:

```
expires epoch;
etag off;
if_modified_since off;
add_header Last-Modified "";
```

... which yields the following response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.1
Date: Wed, 24 Sep 2014 16:58:32 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 1116
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

This looks pretty conclusive to me, but the problem still occurs with Chrome 36 for OS X and Opera 24 for OS X (although Firefox 29 and 32 do the right thing). Chrome is content to grab files from its cache without even referring to the server.

Here's a detailed example, with headers pulled from Chrome's Network debug panel. The first time Chrome fetches /app/resources/states.json, Chrome reports

```
Remote Address:75.144.159.89:8765
Request URL:http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/app/resources/screens.json
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

with request headers:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:Basic dm9sdGFpcndlYjp2b2x0YWly
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
DNT:1
Host:suitable.dyndns.org:8765
Referer:http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

and response headers:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:2369
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
Date:Wed, 24 Sep 2014 17:19:46 GMT
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Server:nginx/1.4.1
```

Again, all fine and good. But, when I change the user (by restarting Chrome and then reloading the parent page), I get the following Chrome report:

```
Remote Address:75.144.159.89:8765
Request URL:http://suitable.dyndns.org:8765/app/resources/states.json
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from cache)
```

with no apparent contact to the server.

This doesn't seem to happen with all files. A few .js files are cached, most are not; none of the .css files seem to be cached; all the .html files are cached, and all of the .json files are cached.

How can I tell the browser (I'm looking at you, Chrome!) that these files are good at the moment it requests them, but will never again be good? Is this a Chrome bug? (If so, it's strange that Opera also shows the problem.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I've found the problem. Apparently "Cache-Control: no-cache" is insufficient to tell the browser to, um, not cache the data. I added "no-store":

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache
```

and that did the trick. No more caching by Chrome or Opera.

Comment: Is it in the webserver-configuration you set this parameter?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, with json being cached...

If you control the client application-code, a possible workaround is to just add a random-value query-parameter at the end of the URL.

So instead of calling:

```
http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/app/resources/screens.json
```

you call, for example:

```
http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/app/resources/screens.json?rand=rrrrrrrrrr
```

where `rrrrrrrrrr` is some random-value that is different in each call.

Then, the browser will not be able to reuse any cached values.

Comment: Very nice, jquery implementation also uses this method by adding `?_=(new Date()).getTime()` to the url.